# R - " missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed "

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to execute the following code in R

```
comments = c("no","yes",NA)
for (l in 1:length(comments)) {
    if (comments[l] != NA) print(comments[l]);
}
```

But I'm getting an error

```
Error in if (comments[l] != NA) print(comments[l]) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

check the command : `NA!=NA` : you'll get the result `NA`, hence the error message.

You have to use the function `is.na` for your `if`statement to work (in general, it is always better to use this function to check for `NA` values) :

```
comments = c("no","yes",NA)
for (l in 1:length(comments)) {
    if (!is.na(comments[l])) print(comments[l])
}
[1] "no"
[1] "yes"
```

Comment: ...check NA with is.na(), and in my case, accept the brutal reality that it's not NULL and that both NA and NULL exist.

Comment: @Chris there is a `is.null` function though ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Can you change the if condition to this:

```
if (!is.na(comments[l])) print(comments[l]);
```

You can only check for NA values with is.na().

Comment: @user3582590: please consider accepting answers that actually answer your question, by clicking the little checkmark under the vote count of the answer. This identifies the most helpful answers for future readers.